# Json schema validation for object which may have two forms

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I'm trying to figure out how to validate a JSON object which may have 2 forms.

for examples
when there is no data available, the JSON could be

```
{
  "student": {}
}
```

when there is data available, the JSON could be

```
{
  "student":{
  "id":"someid",
  "name":"some name",
  "age":15
 }
}
```

I wrote the JSON schema in this way, but it seems not working

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "JSON schema validation",
    "properties": {
        "student": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "required": [],
                    "properties": {}
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "id",
                        "name",
                        "age"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/student/id",
                            "type": [
                                "string",
                                "null"
                            ]
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/student/name",
                            "type": [
                                "string",
                                "null"
                            ]
                        },
                        "age": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/student/age",
                            "type": [
                                "number"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering is there a way to validate it. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To start with, you cannot use that value for `$id`, as that's reserved for the meta-schema. Some implementations may throw an error as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty `properties` object, and an empty `required` object, do nothing.

JSON Schema is constraints based, in that if you don't explicitly constrain what is allowed, then it is allowed by default.

You're close, but not quite. The `const` keyword can take any value, and is what you want in your first item of `allOf`.
You can test the following schema here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/Kz1C0

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/myawesomeschema",
  "title": "JSON schema validation",
  "properties": {
    "student": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "const": {}
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "id",
            "name",
            "age"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            "name": {
              "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            "age": {
              "type": [
                "number"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to upvote and accept answers. If you'd like to buy me a coffee, please see a link on my profile.